# Why my EditText view cannot bring up soft keyboard in Android even I force it to show?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I have an EditText view in a fragment and when showing that fragment, I need to let it get focus and the soft keyboard pops up to allow user type in directly, however, the EditText view seems can only get focus but not show the keyboard even though I manually force it to show. The user has to touch it to bring up the soft keyboard. I tried to get a minimum app to reproduce this, it's simply an activity with an EditText. Any idea?

Activity

```
package com.example.litaos.testeditview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        editText.requestFocus();
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.litaos.testeditview.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:hint="Hello World!"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not enough to just request focus. Please try adding following code to your onCreate method:

```
if(editText.requestFocus()) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Ha, it works! But I have one fragment that may need to hide the keyboard. I haven't tried it there since it take more time to test in that case. Will update. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding  **requestFocus** ?

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email_address"
                    style="@style/baseEditTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
                    <requestFocus/>
                </EditText>
```