# Why DialogFragment will hide the keyboard for its EditText view when first navigated to it in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

In one of my app's fragment, I need to show a DialogFragment with an EditText, however, when it is shown, the soft keyboard is gone. I need to touch the EditText so that the keyboard can be shown, even though it has the focus and I manually set the input method to be shown which should make it auto show up.  **I actually know how** to solve the problem by observing the viewtree using code below

```
EditView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (!isKeyBoardVisible()) {
                    if (EditView.hasFocus()) {
                        getActivity().getWindow()
                                .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                        Utils.showSoftKeyboard(getContext(), searchView);
                    } 
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is that I have EditText view in many places and they seems doesn't work in all these places. So I need to add the code above everywhere which I don't think is a great idea. I want to know **WHY** EditText view will hide the soft keyboard in such situation so that I can come up with some better solution or persuade myself it is necessary to do so. An minimum app you can play around is shown below
Activity

```
package com.example.litaos.testeditview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.see_fragment);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TestDialogFragment testDialogFragment = new TestDialogFragment();
                testDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TestDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.litaos.testeditview.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/see_fragment"
        android:text="See First Fragment!"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </Button>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

DialogFragment

```
package com.example.litaos.testeditview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "addTestDialogFragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);
        EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        if (editText.requestFocus()) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

DialogFragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:hint="Click Here!"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </EditText>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to use an observer to achieve this. These two lines of code solve your problem easily.

```
EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
if(editText.requestFocus()) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
```

EDIT:
I am just going to assume that it's the single EditText, like in the minimal version posted above. This is how I solved a similar issue and it works. Note: I am using AlertDialog instead of a DialogFragment.

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Title");

    //inflate custom layout for editText (with appropriate margins and dimensions)
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText input = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialog);
    if(input.requestFocus()) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           //OK button action
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //cancel button action
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    dialog.show();
```

And the dialog XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, you answered me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364025/why-my-edittext-view-cannot-bring-up-soft-keyboard-in-android-even-i-force-it-to . However, this method doesn't work for EditText view inside the DialogFragment. It works for a simple activity with EditText view, not for DialogFragment

Comment: Hey, I did not notice it was you again. Sorry about that. Anyway, it's weird it does not work with a DialogFragment. Does your DialogFragment contain a lot of elements, or just the one EditText?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to show soft keyboard when a view starts so you only need to put this line of code in relevant activity tag in manifest :

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Comment: It's actually not the activity itself, but the DialogFragment

Comment: And if I add this in the manifest for the above sample app, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, as I said in the post, I actually know how to solve this problem reliably, but I don't know why the keyboard is hidden in the first place.